# shorthand for conditions like (x === y) || (x === z)?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I want to make my condition easier to read and wandering if it is possible to simplify this Scenario:

```
if((x === y)||(x === z)){...}
//and this one: 
x = (x === y) || (x === z)? ... : ...; 

//To something like: 
if(x === (y || z)){...}
x = x === (y || z) ?  ... : ...;
```

This would get rid of the tons of brackets and variable duplication as well as "sounding" logical (at least for me): 
if this var x is this or that then I do this.

Especially when x is some long object reference e.g.:

```
this.someObject.KeyOfKeys[200].language === this.someOtherObject.KeyY.languages[10] || ...;
```

Or how do you deal with logical "easy" but cumbersome to write conditions?

Comment: Yep, in operator won't work. I forgot it works on properties, not values. So, will work on (in case of arrays) indices, not values.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to outsource the comparison/assignment to a private function that does only that and has a good name describing what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: maybe this is the right place for you https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Pac0 where does it say OP wants to get the value that was checked? I might have missed it.

Comment: @Pac0 ah, maybe. That is currently just assigning a boolean. telion, can you please clarify if you're trying to get the value that was successfully compared against OR do you just want to check if a value is included in a set of values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) like so:

```
if ([y, z].includes(x)) { ... }
x = [y, z].includes(x) ? ... : ...;
```

As noted in the comments, this will not work with IE11 and older browsers.

Comment: Includes does not work in IE so should be used with caution

Comment: I'm all in favor of using all possible code that doesn't work in IE, to finally force the world to use a modern browser and spare us a lot of extra work.